# Conquest = usurpation?

Tags: constitution, authority

In the context of establishing a lawfully constituted authority, does **conquest**<sup>1</sup> differ from **usurpation**<sup>2</sup>?

How is conquest different from usurpation, which is an unlawful way of establishing an authority?

What exactly gives a certain person authority, such that the subjects are obliged to obey him? Is it force? Is it ability to govern well?

<sup>1</sup> [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/39432#eid8568028): "The action of gaining by force of arms; acquisition by war; subjugation of a country, etc."

<sup>2</sup>[*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/220720#eid16032823): "to assume or arrogate to oneself (political power, rule, authority, etc.) by force"

Comment: Unless you have a specific reference with a political flavour in mind, this question may be a significantly better fit to the English language & usage stack exchange site.

Comment: @Geremia: Really, how else is "lawful" authority established in the first place?  Every country's "lawful" government was established by a string of conquests, often interspersed with usurpations.  Try British history for a series of examples.  (Downvoted because it displays a serious disconnection from the real world :-))

Comment: In my opinion this is a good question relating to the nature of legal obligation in a political society. Answers could, for example, refer to Kelsen's Pure Theory of Law. This subject is Jurisprudence in the sense of Legal Theory. This sits somewhere between Law and Politics My experience of Law SE is that it is not keen on Legal Theory questions I think mainly because, although Legal Theory is a standard part of a law degree in the United Kingdom it is not common in US law degrees. So I think Politics SE would be the best place for it.

Comment: **What exactly gives a certain person authority** ... " -- The Lady of the Lake, her arm clad in the purest shimmering samite, held aloft Excalibur from the bosom of the water, signifying by divine providence that I, Arthur, was to carry Excalibur. That is why I am your king. -- Listen. Strange women lying in ponds distributing swords is no basis for a system of government. Supreme executive power derives from a mandate from the masses, not from some farcical aquatic ceremony!"

Comment: Ultimately authority is a broad consensus that someone has authority. Sometimes that consensus comes about through (real or imagined) force: everybody agrees that ignoring or resisting the ruler's authority will lead to reprisals they don't want. Sometimes it comes about through tradition: everybody agrees that the ruler "should" have authority (because they were elected according to traditional processes, because they inherited according to traditional definitions of inheritance and descent, etc). Tradition was often originally backed by force, but may now not have been for a very long time.

Comment: Likewise "ability to govern well" is related to authority only in that how well a ruler governs (or appears to govern, or appears to be able to govern in the future) may affect enough people's opinion/belief in the ruler's authority to shift the consensus one way or the other.

Comment: Most (would-be) usurpers claim to have legal authority, and so do many invaders: in the past, often through descent from a lawful monarch (as the would-be James VII or Charles Edward Stewart); or to have been appointed as a lawful heir (William of Normandy); elected via some disputed procedure (like Trump tried); or to be taking office temporarily to allow lawful elections and prevent anarchy (another popular third world coup reason).

Comment: @James K: Depends on how effectively one can wield that sword - or more modern weapons.  "All political power comes from the barrel of a gun" - Mao

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A *usurpation* is when the ruler of a political entity (state, country, region, city, organisation, whatever) is forcefully replaced by a different ruler from within. But there is no change to the sovereignty of the entity. It's the same entity with the same borders and the same political status under new management. This usually happens from the inside (although external support can of course also help). The term is mostly used historically, though. Nowadays an event like that would be referred to as a "coup" or "putsch".

A *conquest*, on the other hand, was an event where one political entity forcefully took over another political entity through an offensive war. A successful conquest resulted in the conquered entity losing its sovereignty. Either in form of a *subjugation*, where it officially stayed intact but unofficially became a non-sovereign puppet subservient to the conquering entity. Or in form of an *annexation*, where the conquered territories became a part of the conquering entity. For example, in World War II, Nazi Germany [*subjugated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vichy_France) France but [*annexed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectorate_of_Bohemia_and_Moravia) Czech.

Throughout history, subjugations or annexations often meant that the conquerors would replace the leadership of the conquered entity, but that does not necessarily need to happen. When the conquerors believe that the conquered leadership will now be loyal to them, then it is very well possible that they leave them in power in order to ensure a smooth transition to the new status quo.

Note that the concept of "[right of conquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_of_conquest)" is officially no longer a thing in international law. The international community is reluctant nowadays to recognize claims legitimized solely by force.

Comment: "Nazi Germany subjugated France but annexed Czech". Meh. Germany occupied part of France initially, but by '43 [all of it](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/France_map_Lambert-93_with_regions_and_departments-occupation_evolution.PNG). It was more like salami tactics. And the Czech was "partially-annexed" according to Wikipedia, apparently because only  Sudetenland was formally annexed. The Protectorate was another "legal fiction" that the Nazis used mask their occupation of the whole country. Not that diff from France from '43 onwards.

Comment: Wikipedia even adds 'the German authorities intentionally allowed the protectorate "all the trappings of independence" in order to encourage the Czech inhabitants to collaborate with them. However, despite the protectorate having its own postage stamps and presidential guard, real power lay with the Nazi authorities. [...] German rule was moderate by Nazi standards during the first months of the occupation. The Czech government and political system, reorganized by Hácha, continued in formal existence.'

Comment: In slight difference with Vichy France, where Petain retained a nominal but ineffective multi-party system (while continuously arguing for authoritarian rule to save France from *décadence*), in the Protectorate, the political system was turned into a fake-clone of the Nazi one "after the establishment of the Protectorate all political parties were outlawed, with the exception of the National Partnership (Národní souručenství)."

Answer (score 3):

'Usurpation' is an old-fashioned word, usually used in the context of kingdoms, where one person vaguely within the line of succession grabs power from the current legitimate king. Today we tend to use the following terms:

- **Coup d'état**: A group internal to the government power structure tries to seize control of the government
- **Rebellion**: a group of citizens outside the government power structure tries to seize control
- **Invasion/occupation**: a group entirely external to the nation (usually a foreign government) tries to seize control

Authority is always granted by the people being ruled, who must consent (in one way or another) to being ruled. Sometimes this may involve force, where the police and military are used to coerce obedience from citizens, but its worth remembering that most people, most of the time, don't think much about large-scale government unless they have specific needs or problems that the government is/isn't addressing. Even in totalitarian regimes the government is a distant thing for most people, who may not like the actions of their leaders but go about their daily lives without much impact from it. They cede authority to the leaders through inaction and diffidence. Where people don't consent to being ruled by certain leaders, there is inevitable unrest and occasional insurrection, which leads to the general degradation of the political system over time.